# How can I check If a message exists in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to have some kind of reaction roles into my bot. For that I have to test If the message ID that the User sends to the bot is valid. Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) as long as you also know what channel you're looking in.

If the message is in the same channel the user sent the ID in then you can use `message.channel` to get the channel or if it's in another channel then you have to get that channel using its ID using `message.guild.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID)`.

So your code could be like this if it's in the same channel:

```js
const msg = message.channel.messages.fetch(MESSAGE_ID)
```

or if it's in a different channel:

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID)
const msg = channel.messages.fetch(MESSAGE_ID)
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this, but if the message doesn't exists, the bot just crash. Any Ideas how to handel that?

Comment: You can wrap the `fetch` function in a try...catch block. `try { await message.channel.messages.fetch('id') } catch {}`. The empty catch block prevented the error for me.

Comment: No, you should just add a check to see if the message is null.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Discord.js v12)

First you need to define the channel where you want your bot to search for a message.

**(You can find it like this)**

```
const targetedChannel = client.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "<Channel Name>");
```

Then you need to add this function:

```
async function setMessageValue (_messageID, _targetedChannel) {
    let foundMessage = new String();
    
    // Check if the message contains only numbers (Beacause ID contains only numbers)
    if (!Number(_messageID)) return 'FAIL_ID=NAN';

    // Check if the Message with the targeted ID is found from the Discord.js API
    try {
        await Promise.all([_targetedChannel.messages.fetch(_messageID)]);
    } catch (error) {
        // Error: Message not found
        if (error.code == 10008) {
            console.error('Failed to find the message! Setting value to error message...');
            foundMessage = 'FAIL_ID';
        }
    } finally {
        // If the type of variable is string (Contains an error message inside) then just return the fail message.
        if (typeof foundMessage == 'string') return foundMessage;
        // Else if the type of the variable is not a string (beacause is an object with the message props) return back the targeted message object.
        return _targetedChannel.messages.fetch(_messageID);
    }
}
```

After this procedure, just get the function value to another variable:

```
const messageReturn = await setMessageValue("MessageID", targetedChannel);
```

And then you can do with it whetever you want.
Just for example you can edit that message with the following code:

```
messageReturn.edit("<Your text here>");
```